# How can I append a number to a string in Racket?

Tags: python, racket, string-concatenation

Python : `xx = "p" + "y" + str(3)` => `xx == "py3"`
How can I get the same result using Racket?

```
(string-append "racket" (number->string 5) " ")
```

Is there another way in Racket, similar to the Python example above, to append a number to a string?

Comment: Did you try your Python example?

Comment: I try: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.   before this question, python auto coerce the number to a string in my mind

Answer (score 13):

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v5.3.5.
-> (~a "abc" "def")
"abcdef"
-> (~a "abc" 'xyz 7 )
"abcxyz7"
->
```

Answer (score 11):

<s>Python automatically coerces the number to a string, while Racket will *not* do so.</s> Neither Racket nor Python will coerce the number into a string. That is why you must use `number->string` explicitly in Racket, *and `str()` in Python* (`"p" + str(3)`). You may also find Racket's `format` function to behave similarly to some uses of Python's `%` operator:

```
# Python
"py %d %f" % (3, 2.2)

;; Racket
(format "rkt ~a ~a" 3 2.2)
```

But there is no Racket *nor Python* equivalent to `"foo" + 3` that I know of.

[Answer edited per my mistake. I was confusing Python behavior with JavaScript, misled by OP]